# spring basic authentication is not worlking in wildfly 8.2 while same is working fine jboss as 7.1

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly-8

i have updated my j boss 7.1 to wild fly 8.2 .but same war file working on 7.2 however not in wild fly 8.2.i getting problem in authentication .War deployed perfectly in WF 8.2 .

> web.xml

```
<filter>

<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>

<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>

<!--    <security-constraint>

<web-resource-collection>

<web-resource-name>AgencyPortalUI</web-resource-name>

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

<http-method>GET</http-method> 

    <http-method>POST</http-method>

</web-resource-collection>

<user-data-constraint>

<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>

</user-data-constraint>

</security-constraint> -->

<session-config>

<!-- 15 minutes 900000 milliseconds -->

<session-timeout>100</session-timeout>

</session-config>

</web-app>
```

> and my jboss configuration ,same on wildfly

```
        <security-domains>

            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">

                <authentication>

                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">

                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>

                    </login-module>

                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="optional">

                        <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>

                        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>

                        <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>

                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>

                    </login-module>

                </authentication>

            </security-domain>

            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">

                <authorization>

                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>

                </authorization>

            </security-domain>

            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">

                <authorization>

                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>

                </authorization>

            </security-domain>

        </security-domains>

    </subsystem>
```

> and my code

```
try {



LOGGER.info("before authenticate {}");

userTO = restEasyPortalServiceProxy.getLoginService().authenticate(

userName, userPass);

LOGGER.info("After authenticate : {}", userTO);

userSessionData.setAuthToken(userTO.getAuthToken());

}
```

Comment: have you tried accessing your URL using a web browser?

Comment: Yes,page are opening but when we press a login button :getting error with 500 internal server error with above error msg is response is closed